# Bootstrap multiple inline dropdowns and buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add an inline bootstrap dropdown, text field, dropdown and then a button. The problem I have is that the second dropdown before the green button still as a radius on the top right and bottom corners, as seen in the screen shot below:

[image]

My question is, is there a way to do this just using the bootstrap mark up, or will I just have to target the second dropdown with custom CSS? The code I have so far is below:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.dropdown-menu:nth-child(2){border-radius:0;}
```